# select a file path to save form print screen in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox1 and a button. When I press the button the program takes a screenshot of my form and saves it to the path given in the code.
What is the code so I can select the path to save my print screen in jpg format?
The file name of the file should be the text entered into textbox1.

My code:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button4.Click

        'send keys with Alt key
        SendKeys.SendWait("%({PRTSC})")
        My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage().Save("C:\temp\form.jpg")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file name of the file should be the text entered into textbox1

This seems like a stupid answer...but it's what you asked for:

```
My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage().Save(TextBox1.Text)
```

--------- EDIT ----------

> Thanks, and how to select the path where to save it? And how to add
>   the extension?

Use the [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can also use the [Control.DrawToBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) function instead of Alt-PrtSc, and actually specify the [JPEG format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx) when you save the image:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        sfd.Filter = "JPEG Files(*.JPG)|*.JPG"
        If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Size.Width, Me.Size.Height)
                Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("FileName: " & sfd.FileName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error Saving Screenshot")
            End Try
            MessageBox.Show("FileName: " & sfd.FileName, "Screenshot Saved")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to select the path where to save it? And how to add the extension?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. Sorry for the late answer but I had to go.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the textbox's `Text` property, so...

```
textbox1.Text
```

Comment: Thanks, but where to put the textbox1.text? Sorry, I am not a pro in VB